# Flexbox и Internet Explorer 10

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox

Уважаемые, прошу поделиться опытом применения замечательной технологии Flexbox для всеми любимых браузеров Internet Explorer 10 и ниже. Ниже код и сразу вопрос "**почему блок навигации сбивается в кучу в IE10**, в 9-й версии вообще, как я понял flex не работает. Что с префиксами ,что без...никакого результата(интересно, вот [тут](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLJ5NW5T60UphOVDsbAC97JQ2KEprVgh2r&v=cr-cFGWsHM8) профи не советует префиксы ставить). **Поделитесь в целом опытом совмещения Flexbox с IE** :

```
<div class="section">
  <div class="banner">
    <p class="logo">Наша компания</p>
    <a href="#">Клиенты</a>
    <a href="#">О нас</a>
    <a href="#">Вакансии</a>
  </div>
</div>



html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
body {
  font-size: 1.1em; /* currently ems cause chrome bug misinterpreting rems on body element */
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "Roboto", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #222;
}

.banner {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: end;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
      -ms-flex-align: end;
          align-items: flex-end;
}

.banner a {
  padding: 8px 2%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
}

.banner a:hover, .banner a.highlight {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.section {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 4rem;
  margin: 0;

}
```

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Вы бы еще спросили как для ие7 и 8 его "использовать".

Никак. Применять другие стили (`float`, `inline-block`).

Comment: Перечитайте ещё раз просьбу или хоть название темы, если тяжело читать , если не знаете ,что написать, то лучше и не пишите.

Comment: перечитала и еще раз напишу! Заменить флекс на другие стили для ие10 и ниже!!!

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox   почему объявлена поддержка префиксами ИЕ10?

Comment: @ЮрийБеляев написано же : `частичная` поддержка с приставкой

Comment: ну ,я видел ,что частичная поддержка...интересовал частный случай ,упомянутый выше. + просил поделится опытом. Можно же просто написать ,что в ИЕ10-  флекс не использую ,а не показывать свою мегазначимость(не вас имею ввиду)

Comment: @ЮрийБеляев я вообще не применяю flex ни где , есть блочная вёрстка и css-table - и поверьте мало чем отличается от флексбокс

Comment: @Geyan посоветуйте что-нибудь для css-table в современной вёрстке

Comment: @ЮрийБеляев надо применять и всё,https://habrahabr.ru/post/281254/

Answer (score 1):

```
@media screen and (min-width:0\0) {  
    /* стили для IE9 - IE10 */  
}
```